# "Trash" equivalent for 12.04

Tags: 12.04, trash, alias, rm

I recently updated my Ubuntu version to 12.04.

I have aliased `rm` to the command `trash`, and now that I have upgraded, there is no longer a command called `trash`. Is there an equivalent for 12.04? I just want to move files to a trash can before I delete them, so I don't go delete my all of my code, which I have done before.

Comment: Could you check whether the package `trash-cli`is installed in your system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing the trash-cli utility:

```
sudo apt-get install trash-cli
```

Usage:

```
trash-put           trash files and directories.
trash-empty         empty the trashcan(s).
trash-list          list trashed files.
trash-restore       restore a trashed file.
trash-rm            remove individual files from the trashcan.</pre>
```

For more information, check the [GitHub documentation](https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli#trash-cli---command-line-interface-to-freedesktoporg-trash)

Comment: Super. Works fine. For future visitors, instead of `alias rm='trash'` I now have `alias rm='trash-put'`.

Comment: They changed restore-trash to trash-restore and list-trash to trash-list. (https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli/blob/master/README.rst)

Answer (score 0):

The comment above seems outdated or wrong. It seems that list-trash -> trash-list

Here is what i have in my rc file

- `alias del='trash'`
- `alias dell='trash-list'`
- `alias undel='trash-restore'`

Comment: If you have a correction to an existing an answer, please [suggest an edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/315687/edit) to do so